# Under what conditions are continuous functions closed in the compact-open topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

If $X$ is compactly generated and $Y$ is a metric space, then $C(X,Y)$ is a closed subset of $Y^X$ in the compact-open topology. My question is, when the codomain $Y$ is no longer metric (or even uniform) are there established conditions for when $C(X,Y)$ is closed in the compact-open topology?

Comment: A nice and quite extensive book on such comparisons between function space topologies is [McCoy and Ntantu](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540193029). I'd check there first. No access to a library anymore (except my personal one), but I have browsed it in earlier days...

Comment: My conjecture: if $X$ is a space such that $C(X,Y)$ is closed in $Y^X$ for all spaces $Y$ (or maybe in some large enough class) then $X$ is compactly generated. Just a gut feeling..

Comment: You should give precise definitions of $Y^X$ and $C(X,Y)$.